# Drools: Variables can not be used inside bindings

Tags: drools, drools-planner, optaplanner

I get the error

> Variables can not be used inside bindings

on the following Drools-Rule Code

```
rule "minGapsBetweenAppointments"
when
    $leftAssignment : AppointmentRequest(feasibleAppointment != null)
    $totalValue : Number( ) from accumulate(
            AppointmentRequest(feasibleAppointment != null,
                    $leftAssignment.requestId != requestId,
                    $quality : this.getOccupiedSurroundingsValue($leftAssignment)),
            sum( $quality )
            ) // ERROR LINE
then
    scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, $totalValue.intValue());
end
```

Although i found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444470/summing-values-of-an-objects-map-gives-me-errors) from another question, it's not helping me much, as I need to call function **getOccupiedSurroundingsValue** for all other AppointmentRequests, as they're related.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What version of drools is this?

Comment: If you add a method on `AppointmentRequest` called `getOccupiedSurroundingsValueFromLeftAssignement()` and refactor the DRL to `$quality : getOccupiedSurroundingsValueFromLeftAssignement()`, does it work?
Your code should work I think, just wondering if this change is a workaround or not.

Comment: The drools version is the one packed with optaplanner 6.0.0.0Beta5

Comment: I guess it would work, but where would I get the data of the left assignment from?

Comment: My mistake. I thought the $leftAssignment came from the AppointmentRequest itself.

Answer (score 0):

That code should work. There's nothing wrong with it as far as I can see.
Double check if you it's exactly the same as the code you're executing it. I use similar code in my examples and those work.

If it's OK, then it might be a bug in Drools Expert.
There are 2 ways to proceed:

- The easy way: repost this question on [the drools mailing list](http://www.jboss.org/drools/lists), maybe Edson or Wolfgang sees something I don't. Post a jira if no one sees a user-mistake.
- The fastest way to solve your problem: create a new test in [MiscTest](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-compiler/src/test/java/org/drools/compiler/integrationtests/MiscTest.java) that proves your case and submit it as pull request. Either you find out what you're doing wrong or you prove without a shadow of a doubt there's a bug we need to fix asap :)